# Converting into dictionary

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I need to convert this data structure into multiple dictionaries.

I have a datastructure, I want to convert it into dictionaries to make the script work.

```
p= {u'data': [{u'_id': u'5cd514f5b52af58fc58df832',
            u'encap': u'vlan-18',
            u'hostname': u'CGST',
            u'ip': u'10.0.0.7',
            u'mac': u'00:10:46:D6:00:40'},
           {u'_id': u'5cd514f5b52af58fc58df830',
            u'encap': u'vlan-15',
            u'hostname': u'GBTW',
            u'ip': u'10.0.4.1',
            u'mac': u'00:40:39:B6:F8:3A'}]}
```

Can "mac" be the key and the rest be the item with 1 dictionary each.
Something like :

```
{00:10:46:D6:00:40:{ip: '10.0.0.7',encap:'vlan-18',hostname:'CGST'}}
{00:40:39:B6:F8:3A:{ip: '10.0.4.1',encap:'vlan-15',hostname:'GBTW'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dict comprehension

**Ex:**

```
p= {u'data': [{u'_id': u'5cd514f5b52af58fc58df832',
            u'encap': u'vlan-18',
            u'hostname': u'CGST',
            u'ip': u'10.0.0.7',
            u'mac': u'00:10:46:D6:00:40'},
           {u'_id': u'5cd514f5b52af58fc58df830',
            u'encap': u'vlan-15',
            u'hostname': u'GBTW',
            u'ip': u'10.0.4.1',
            u'mac': u'00:40:39:B6:F8:3A'}]}


print({i.pop("mac"): i for i in p["data"]})
```

**Output:**

```
{u'00:10:46:D6:00:40': {u'_id': u'5cd514f5b52af58fc58df832',
                        u'encap': u'vlan-18',
                        u'hostname': u'CGST',
                        u'ip': u'10.0.0.7'},
 u'00:40:39:B6:F8:3A': {u'_id': u'5cd514f5b52af58fc58df830',
                        u'encap': u'vlan-15',
                        u'hostname': u'GBTW',
                        u'ip': u'10.0.4.1'}}
```